# C# and entity framework objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

try to made my first c# programme, with vs2010 and entity framework.
This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ValinorEntities ve = new ValinorEntities();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = ve.item_groups;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "item_group_name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "item_group_id";

        var departmentQuery = from d in ve.items
                              from g in ve.item_groups
                              where d.item_group_id_fk == g.item_group_id
                              select new { d.item_name, g.item_group_name, d.item_id, d.item_number };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = departmentQuery;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

        comboBox1.DataSource = ve.item_groups;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "item_group_name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "item_group_id";
    }

    private void btn_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            item item = new Valinor.item();

            item.item_name = textBox1.Text;
            item.item_number = textBox2.Text;
            item.item_group_id_fk = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            ve.AddToitems(item);
            ve.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Insert successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert failed" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            item c = ve.items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.item_id == id);

            c.item_name = textBox1.Text;
            c.item_number = textBox2.Text;
            c.item_group_id_fk = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;                
            ve.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Save successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Save failed" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

It's working but i have a few problem.

- What should I write a `comboBox1.SelectedValue` to the correct item is selected after clicking on a cell?
- In the `btnSave_Click` function the value of`textbox3` refer to ID, which is not very elegant solution. How can I object to replace it?
- If I know of such references, such as these:

  `textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`
  `textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();`

could be avoided somehow.
To do this, however zakell that `dataGridView1_CellMouseClick` fügvénynél not refer the value of the cell but also the object. This can be to solve it?

Comment: Ummmm whats the question???????/

Comment: @user: could you please post a screenshot of your form?  I'm thinking there're supposed to be 3 textboxes and a combobox at the top which show the current rows values.. maybe?

Comment: Here is the picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9jfcr.png The question is how to change the cell value reference to the ef object, but my question is written at the end.